# Deploy closed source aar maven repo to github

Tags: android, git, maven, github, gradle

I am using the following guide to publish a closed source aar as maven repo on github:
http://andydyer.org/blog/2014/10/05/hosting-android-dependencies-on-github/

The github repo I am publishing to: https://github.com/tabishfayyaz/test-sdk

In my gradle.build file I have:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://github.com/tabishfayyaz/test-sdk/blob/master" }
} 

dependencies {
    compile 'com.adscendmedia.sdk:adscendmedia:1.0.1'
}
```

However Android studio results in following error:
Failed to resolve: com.adscendmedia.sdk:adscendmedia:1.0.1

Any ideas whats wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the raw link, try changing blob for raw:

http://downright-amazed.blogspot.com/2011/09/hosting-maven-repository-on-github-for.html

Comment: using the @aar doesn't help but replacing 'blob' with 'raw' worked